# How to find the car speed on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-location, core-motion

I want to find the car speed on my iPhone when driving so what should I use and how?
Core Motion or Core Location? Is there any documentation or sample code?

Comment: You will need CoreLocation. The theory is tho calculate the distance between to GPS coordinates. Then take the time between the two points and see how much distance is travled in that time.

Comment: thank u so much thats the original logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey - You'll want core location for this.

There is a really good tutorial here - http://www.vellios.com/2010/08/16/core-location-gps-tutorial/ that I followed once. There is a whole series but this one shows you how to calculate the position and speed of your device. There is a sample project to download too. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Mashhadi. If you are happy with it could you mark my post as the answer by clicking the tick please? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, hope you find the tutorial useful.

Comment: @chris: this code is not finding the accurate speed & i am unable to find the bug, do you have any idea?

Comment: What is not accurate? Have you checked the different values that you are using to calculate the speed to verify that they are correct? Is the GPS location accurate?

Comment: infect it shows lat & long but do not change speed it show -1.0000 speed.
& plz guide me that it could be checked on wifi or only gprs?

Comment: update you tutorial link as it is saying "Internal Server Error"

Answer (score 2):

`CoreMotion` would not help you much, because it is an abstraction of the device's accelerometer and the gyroscope. You could measure acceleration and deceleration and computing the speed from basic physics, but I would not do so.

I would use the `CoreLocation` frameworkd and rely on GPS positioning. There is a ton of sample code out there and a WWDC10 video as well, so go ahead and look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CLLocationManager` and speed property in `CLLocation` class

```
- (void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
            fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    NSLog("[Location Updated] \n Speed: %.2fm/s (%.1fkm/h)", newLocation.speed, newLocation.speed*3600/1000);

}
```

Comment: I am always getting -1 for speed.